# java fatal error when using hadoop snappy

Tags: java, hadoop, snappy

I just installed *hadoop snappy* and when I tried to use `hadoop fs -text /xxxx/xxx/xx/xx.snappy` command to see the content of a *snappy file* in `hdfs`, it throws a fatal error:

```
2015-01-06 13:06:39.248 java[22668:285995] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
15/01/06 13:06:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/01/06 13:06:41 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
15/01/06 13:06:41 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
15/01/06 13:06:42 WARN snappy.SnappyCompressor: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load libsnappy.1.dylib (dlopen(libsnappy.1.dylib, 9): image not found)!
15/01/06 13:06:42 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
15/01/06 13:06:42 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
15/01/06 13:06:42 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
15/01/06 13:06:42 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000100f167a7, pid=22668, tid=4867
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3037a7]  jni_GetStaticObjectField+0x92
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /cores/core or core.22668
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/yichao/asup-rc-client/hs_err_pid22668.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Abort trap: 6 (core dumped)
```

My system is OSX 10.10.1 (14B25)

Anyone can give me some help to solve this problem, please?

Comment: looks like the Mac SIP problem which prevent non-notarization library from loading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection. but that started from 10.11.